How to force "et al." instead of author list for first citation in LaTex with natbib and apa7
I am writing a text in APA7 style and according to my research, a publication with more than two  authors always gets cited as (Firstauthor et al., year) in in-text-citations according to APA7 (https://www.easybib.com/guides/citation-guides/apa-format/citing-source-with-multiple-authors-apa/ or https://www.scribbr.com/apa-style/in-text-citation/)
I am working in LaTex, which I am new to. The program keeps forcing the first mention of a source in-text as (Firstauthor, Secondauthoer & Thirdautor, year).
Here is my example code:
\documentclass[natbib]{apa7} 

\begin{document}
citep\citep{oliver1992}

citep\citep{oliver1992}

citep\citep{oliver1992}

\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}

and the refs.bib file:
@article{oliver1992,
  title={Impact of a needle exchange program on potentially infectious syringes in public places.},
  author={Oliver, K.J. and Friedman, S.R. and Maynard, H. and Magnuson, L. and Des Jarlais, D.C.},
  journal={JAIDS Journal of Acquired Immune Deficiency Syndromes},
  volume={5},
  edition={5},
  pages={534},
  year={1992},
  doi = {}
} 

This produces the following output:

As you can see, the first time, the citation is cited as all autheors instead of et al.
These suggestions from other questions did not help so far:

changed \documentclass[natbib]{apa7} into \documentclass[natbib]{apa6} -> no difference

included \bibliographystyle{apacite} -> no difference and warning Class apa7 Warning: \bibliographystyle command ignored on input line 3. 

included \usepackage{apacite} -> no difference

included \usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex} -> citation gets displayed as "?"

included \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} -> citation gets displayed as "?"

included \usepackage{csquotes} and \setcitestyle{authoryear,open={((},close={))}} -> no difference

use \citet{oliver1992}, \citealt{oliver1992}, \citealt*{oliver1992} and \citealp{oliver1992} instead of \citep{oliver1992} -> no difference


My question is twofold:

Did I understand correctly that in APPA7 all in-cite citations with more than 2 authos gets cited as (Firstauthor et al., year). I am asking because all the other APA7 guidelines are implemented correctly when using {apa7} and it confused me that this rule was apparently not implemented.
How can I force LaTex to display all citations as (Firstauthor et al., year), even when they are mentioned the first time? I would also be open to using any "un-elegant" workarounds.

Thank you a lot!!

The apa7 document class does nothing with bibliographies itself, but recommends you use biblatex for your bibliography because biblatex-apa implements APA7. apacite implements APA6 and likely won't be updated. So you can load the apa7 class with the biblatex option, or just add:
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

to your document (without specifying an option in the class).
Then you load your bibliography file with
\addbibresource{yourbibfile.bib}

And use
\printbibliography

to produce the bibliography itself.
Since you're now using biblatex you need to compile using biber not bibtex to process the bibliography.
